# Basic question on math notation of max and min

Tags: notation

When we write $\text{max}\left \{x,y  \right \}$ and $\text{min}\left \{x,y  \right \}$ then what do we actually mean? Does it mean the maximum and minimum of **both** the things that are inside $\left \{  \right \}$. Say $\epsilon = \text{max}\left \{1,3  \right \}$ then what does it exactly mean in a numeric sense? If $x = 1$ and $y = 3$, then is  $\epsilon = \text{max}\left \{1,3  \right \}$ the biggest number formed from $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For real $a$ and $b$ (and in general for any $a$ and $b$ belonging to some order), $\max\{a, b\} = a$ if $a \geq b$; otherwise, $\max\{a, b\} = b$.

Comment: And for minimum is it the opposite? That is, $\text{min}\left \{a,b  \right \}=b$ if $a \geq b$, otherwise, $\text{min}\left \{a,b  \right \} = a$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\max(1,3)$ means the biggest number from both and $\min(1,3)$ means the smallest number.